# Better line breaking in terminal?

Tags: terminal, shell

I am not sure if my request is valid, doable or better than the default option, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

Word-wrapping in a terminal usually bothers me, since it wraps in the middle of the words. Recently I discovered an option for Vim, called `linebreak` which makes word wrapping sane: line breaks are not inserted mid-word.

Is there any option to make word-wrapping a bit more sane in a terminal? Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Any word-wrapping in the Terminal is software doing it for you, e.g. in an editor. At the bash prompt you have the right edge fall into the left edge of next row - nothing else.

Comment: @Hannu I understand. But I hope maybe there's a terminal emulator which has an ability to do that. I use Terminator, and it doesn't seem to have the feature.

Comment: =) well, I have never bothered so, might be there is one. ;-)